How to animate a RecyclerView item outside of the RecyclerView
I’m new to android studio, I’m trying to build a card game.
I used a RecyclerView to display the player's cards (each card is an ImageView). When the player clicks on a card, the card should move to the deck (also an Image View in the center of the main layout in the xml), and then be removed from the the RecyclerView.
But when the item moves outside of the RecyclerView's border it becomes invisible. Is there a way to animate a RecyclerView item outside of the RecyclerView's border?
